# How to set expiration of newsletter confirmation link in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have newsletter in my magento website. I have enable confirmation before subscription from admin configuration. User are getting confirmation link in mail.

But I want to set expiry of that link. Is magento provide default config ?

How can I set expiry of that link ?

Comment: I have a same problem...

Comment: have you got any solution ?

Comment: not yet. I am trying.

Comment: @ChanakaHettiarachchi I got the solution. May be it will help you.... dont forget to upvote the answer if it will help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I just did two things.

1) Add `created_at` field in `newsletter_subscriber` table.

2) Overwrite the following file

> vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

to

> Company/name/Model/Subscriber.php

**Overited Subscriber.php file code**

```
public function confirm($code) // existing function
    {
        $id = $this->getId();
        if ($this->validateConfirmLinkToken($id, $code)) {
            if ($this->getCode() == $code) {
                $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
                    ->setStatusChanged(true)
                    ->save();
                $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    private function validateConfirmLinkToken($customerId, $code) //check validation for token
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $messageManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface');
        if (empty($customerId) || $customerId < 0) {
            $this->_messageManager->addError('Sorry you have not rigts to access this page');
            return false;
        }
        if (!is_string($code) || empty($code)) {
            $params = ['fieldName' => 'code'];
            //$messageManager->addError('Sorry Your subscription confirmation code is not valid.');
            return false;
        }
        $dcode = $this->getCode();
        $dcreated_at = $this->getCreatedAt();
        if (trim($dcode) != trim($code)) {
            //$messageManager->addError('Sorry Your subscription confirmation code is mismatch.');
            return false;
        } elseif ($this->isConfirmationLinkTokenExpired($dcode, $dcreated_at)) {
            //$messageManager->addError('Sorry Your subscription confirmation code is expired.');
            return false;

        }

        return true;
    }

    public function isConfirmationLinkTokenExpired($dcode, $dcreated_at) // check expiration token
    {
        if (empty($dcode) || empty($dcreated_at)) {
            return true;
        }

        $expirationPeriod = '720';

        $currentTimestamp = (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp();
        $tokenTimestamp = (new \DateTime($dcreated_at))->getTimestamp();
        if ($tokenTimestamp > $currentTimestamp) {
            return true;
        }

        $hourDifference = floor(($currentTimestamp - $tokenTimestamp) / (60 * 60));
        if ($hourDifference >= $expirationPeriod) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Hope it will helps to many.

Thanks.